# Java - Problems with Scanner and JTextFields

Tags: java, swing, java.util.scanner, jtextfield

This is my first time using `Scanner` in a `JFrame` with 1 `JTextFields` and 1 `JTextArea` and I have a problem. When I enter string in the textfield, the scanner is able to pick that up with no problem and I can print it out too.

But when I try to enter a string in the textarea, the scanner doesn't pick it up. I have tried setting focusable to false on the textfield, but still the scanner is not picking up the string entered in the textarea.

Any idea why this is happening?

**EDIT**
My mistake. It is 1 `JTextField` and 1 `JTextArea`.

This is my Client class:

```
public class Client implements Runnable{

    //Globals
    Socket sock;
    Scanner input;
    Scanner send = new Scanner(System.in);
    PrintWriter output;

    public Client (Socket X) {
        this.sock = X;
    }

    //@Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            try {
                input = new Scanner(sock.getInputStream());
                output = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
                output.flush();
                CheckStream();
            }
            finally {
                sock.close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception E) {
            System.out.print(E);
        }
    }

    public void Disconnect() throws IOException{
        output.println(ChatRoom.Username + " has disconnected!");
        output.flush();
        sock.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You disconnected!");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void CheckStream() {
        while (true) {
            Receive();
        }
    }

    public void Receive() {
        if (input.hasNext()) {
            String message = input.nextLine();
            //the problem is with "message"
            //it can read the first textfield but not the second
            System.out.println(message);

            if (message.contains("#?!")) {
                String tempCurrUsers = message.substring(3);
                tempCurrUsers = tempCurrUsers.replace("[", "");
                tempCurrUsers = tempCurrUsers.replace("]", "");

                String[] CurrentUsers = tempCurrUsers.split(", ");

                ChatRoom.JL_CurrentUsersDisplay.setListData(CurrentUsers);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(message);
                ChatRoom.TA_ChatDisplay.append(message + "\n");
            }
        }
    }

    public void Send(String X) {
        output.println(ChatRoom.Username + ": " + X);
        output.flush();
        ChatRoom.TF_MessageBox.setText("");
        //ChatRoom.TA_ChatDisplay.append(ChatRoom.Username+": " + X + "\n");

    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: @AndrewThompson u mean in the tag?

Comment: Where have you used the scanner with a text field in the example above?

Comment: *"..mean in the tag?"*  I sure was not referring to SO style tags.  I'm not sure what you were referring to by 'tag'.  What I meant was well explained at each link (two different ways of describing the same thing).

Comment: @NabeelOmer The scanner was initialised in the `run` method and used in the `Receive` method.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think `Scanner` is used in Swing (unless you are talking about a barcode scanner). I believe you want use something like

```
String someText = textField1.getText();
```

Check out [How to Use Text Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html).